# creating a bash script - loop through files

Tags: bash, loops

I was wondering, I need to run `indent` with a bunch of parameters as:

```
indent slithy_toves.c -cp33 -di16 -fc1 -fca -hnl -i4  -o slithy_toves.c
```

What I want is to read each `*.c` and `*.h` files and overwrite them with the same name.

How could I do this in a bash script, so next time I can run the script and do all the indentation at once?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't bother writing a loop - the `find` utility could do it for you already:

```
find . -name \*.[ch] -print0 | xargs -0 indent ....
```

Answer (score 2):

I second [Carl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269354/creating-a-bash-script-loop-through-files/3269377#3269377), but if you do feel the need to use a loop:

```
for filename in *.[ch]; do
    indent "$filename" -cp33 -di16 -fc1 -fca -hnl -i4  -o "$filename"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, `indent` overwrites the input file(s) with the revised source, hence:

```
indent -cp33 -di16 -fc1 -fca -hnl -i4  *.c *.h
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for i in *.c *.h; do
    indent "$i" -cp33 -di16 -fc1 -fca -hnl -i4  -o "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf newdir
mkdir newdir
for fspec in *.[ch] ; do
    indent "${fspec}" -cp33 -di16 -fc1 -fca -hnl -i4  -o "newdir/${fspec}"
done
```

*Then*, you check to make sure all the new files in `newdir/` are okay before you copy them back over the originals manually:

```
cp ${newdir}/* .
```

That last paragraphe is important. I don't care how long I've been writing scripts, I always assume my first attempt will screw up and possible trash my files :-)